Is it possible to prevent side effects? opposite of Scan
Suppose I have a function that returns an output, and also does a side effect, such as writing a new cell to the notebook. I would like to use the function but prevent its side effects. Essentially, I'm looking for the opposite functionality of Scan.
Is this possible?

If the printing of the cell as a side effect was done using Echo, then you could wrap your code in a QuietEcho to suppress it.

How does your function write a new cell to a notebook? You could simply use Block, for example: Block[{Print, Echo, CellPrint}, ...]

You have to be specific about which side effects you wish to suppress. (You cannot say "all". You can list all of them, though. Each one might require a different hack, and some may be impossible to stop.)

Scan returns nothing to the function that calls it.
It can only be usefull if it calls functions like Print,Echo... which have side effects (of course it is also usefull to change some internal state of a object without visible effect).
At the opposite, Map is the equivalent of Scan that returns a value to the function that calls it.
See the documentation of Scan, paragraph "Properties & Relation".
In general the initial code that contains Print, Echo ... should be changed too.
Side effects are not in the philosophy of Mathematica.
Scan may be sometimes used instead of Map to optimize speed or memory consumption.
Note : Until Mathematica 6, Graphics & Co were output by side effect. It's no more the case.
